# How to alias a template function inside a template class

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a need to implement 2 functions inside a templated class, where both functions do similar things, but not everything is the same. My proposed solution was to use `if constexpr` on a single template function, and then have an alias for each function:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
private:
   template <bool test>
   void TestFunc()
   {
      if constexpr(test)
      {
         // Do something
      }
      else
      {
         // Do other stuff
      }
   }
public:
   ?????? TestTrue = TestFunc<true>;
   ?????? TestFalse = TestFunc<false>;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out what should go where the question marks are, so far `using`, `auto` and `const auto` have not worked. I want the user to be able to call `TestTrue()` and `TestFalse()` directly from an object of the class directly.

Comment: `= TestFunc<true>` `TestFunc` is not a type. You can create a pointer to that function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do:

```
void TestTrue() { TestFunc<true>(); }
void TestFalse() { TestFunc<false>(); }
```

I don't think there's a better way.

Comment: I think you're right, but it's somehow disappointing :p

Comment: The compiler will inline it. So it's exactly the same thing. `:)`

Comment: I mean, yeah, but was looking for a spiffy c++17 way to do it

Comment: @cigien Maybe my answer below can alleviate some disappointment. We have the tools, they just aren't pretty :)

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here's the ugly way.

As mentioned in the comments, `TestFunc` is a member function, not a type, so if you want to reference an explicit specialization of it, you'll need to use a [member function pointer](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members). In our case, these will be pointers of the following type.

```
using MemberTestFunction = void (MyClass::*)();
```

We can then acquire pointers to the `true` and `false` specialization of `TestFunc` like so:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
    // ...
    constexpr static MemberTestFunction TestTrue = &MyClass::TestFunc<true>;

    constexpr static MemberTestFunction TestFalse = &MyClass::TestFunc<false>;
};
```

If you're not familiar with pointers to member functions, the syntax for calling `TestTrue` and `TestFalse` may look rather bizarre. If you're inside a member function, you can invoke these functions either by using the `->*` operator, or by using [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) (C++17) from `<functional>`:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
    // ...
    void foo() {
        // Direct call with pointer.
        (this->*TestTrue)();
        // Call using std::invoke.
        std::invoke(TestTrue, this);

    }
};
```

Alternatively, outside of `MyClass`, these calls would look like the following.

```
MyClass<nullptr_t> x;

// Using type deducation.
(x.*decltype(x)::TestTrue)();

// Using fully qualified name.
(x.*MyClass<nullptr_t>::TestTrue)();

// Using std::invoke (with type deducation).
std::invoke(decltype(x)::TestTrue, x);
```

It goes without saying this this is a needlessly obscure way of accomplishing any otherwise simple task. I would not advocate using this technique over creating new functions (as HolyBlackCat suggested) or simply naming `TestFunc<true>()` and `TestFunc<false>()` explicitly at the call site.

Comment: I was trying to minimize the headache of whoever calls the function from outside the class...

Comment: @EyalK. Headache? This would given me a migraine if used in an actual project! I added a short disclaimer to clarify that I'm not suggesting one uses this over a simpler solution. Using a neat abstraction simply because you can is certainty a [bad thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Answer (score 0):

Transform function `TestFunc` to functor:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
 private:
  template <bool test>
  struct TestFunc
  {
    void operator()() {
      if constexpr(test)
      {
        std::cout << "TestTrue\n";
      }
      else
      {
        std::cout << "TestFalse\n";
      }
    }
  };
 public:
  TestFunc<true> TestTrue;
  TestFunc<false> TestFalse;
};

int main()
{
  MyClass<int> myClass;
  myClass.TestTrue();
  myClass.TestFalse();
}
```